# Can you remove a column from a Content Type after data has been added?

Tags: content-type

I'm curious if I add a rating column to my Content Type (Which inherits from Document C.T.) can I remove it later if I find it not to be useful?  What will happen in the document library to those documents that have been rated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To expand a bit on Lukas' answer - yes, you can remove the column from the content type, but that will only mean you won't see that column in the new/edit/display forms when you view or edit properties for documents of that content type.

Unless you specifically remove the column from the document library, it will still exist in the library and any documents for which you have entered data for that column will keep their data, you will just have to create a view that includes that column in order to see or edit that data, since that column will no longer show up in the view/edit forms.

You can take the additional step of, after removing the column from the content type, also removing the column from the library.  In that case, all previously recorded data in that column will be lost.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can remove column from used content type if you later find it useless.

You are only not able to remove content type itself  if is used.